# How to change the up vector of something in Unreal

Tags: mathematics, vector, unreal-4

---

I'm creating a grapple hook mechanic.

The elements of this particular situation are a Player and a grapple point.

---

I would like the top of the player to always be pointing towards this grapple point. (the up vector of the player is pointing along the vector to the point).

The default Unreal CharacterMovementComponent is in the falling movement mode right now, and the player's rotation around the Z axis is determined by the movement input. The X and Y rotations are unchanged.

Because the player's position around this grapple point could be anywhere on the sphere of influence of the rope, I never have a definite axis to rotate around to point the up vector towards the grapple point.

---

How do I achieve something like this?

Comment: Have you tried rotating the player?

Comment: @TomTsagk I've only seen methods to rotate the forward vector of the player, not the upward vector.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Unreal, but from a quick search I found the function `AddActorLocalRotation` which as an argument takes a quaternion, which could describe any type of rotation. Is it worth taking a look at it? Otherwise you might need share with us how you do rotations already, so its easier to suggest something closer to your level.

Comment: @TomTsagk edited the question

Comment: What do you want to rotate and around what axis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to change the up vector of something in Unreal ?" The answer is simple - to change the `upvector` you simply need to change the object's rotation.

To make your `upvector` to point to something - you can use innate function of FMath
especially take a look at: `MakeRotFromXZ` family of functions.
[docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Kismet/UKismetMathLibrary/MakeRotFromXZ/index.html)